# Jenkins Copy to slave plugin is over writing all the files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I have setups jenkins for automation scripts and we have 1 Jenkins server and 5 different Slaves . what i want to do is , i want to copy all the files to main server which is master machine after every run .  I have checked copy to slave plugin but every time with new build it is copy over to existing html report . but we want to have all the test HTML report according to days. So we dont have to go to slave machine to see the results .

let me know how to solve this .

My setup is like

files to copy  (testresults/results.html )

So please help me to get copied all the html report every time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the post action "Archive the artifacts".

In this way you will able to see the previous tests from slaves on the master per build.